# How to application-prod.properties using -Dspring.profiles.active=prod in command line?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, profile

I'm trying to use prod profile,
for that i created an application-prod.properties file with others configuration, and when i run

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

The application.properties is set up instead of the "application-prod.properties" one.

Did I forget some step in here?

Comment: Where did you test it from? ide? terminal? could you add the full command? because it looks like it is missing the order.

Comment: The `application.properties` is set up anyway, regardless the active profile list. `application-prod.properties` can overwrite or add to  `application.properties`'s content when `prod` profile is active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to specify the `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod` setting before the jar.

E.g.,

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

will work, but

```
java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

will not.

Comment: Truly helpful, my Procfile on heroku was something like this ```web: java -jar target/project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -D -Dspring.profiles.active=prod```